# Find the uncertainty in the velocity of an electron and alpha particle respectively when they are located within 15×10^(-8) cm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

recently I was solving questions on uncertainty principle but never came across questions involving system of particles like combination of electron and alpha particle.

I wanted to understand how to deal system of particles while solving uncertainty principle questions.

My initial thought was to calculate total uncertainty in momentum of the system and then using the conservation of momentum, divide this uncertainty in momentum by the respective masses of electron and alpha particle to obtain their respective uncertainty in velocity. Is this approach right?

Comment: Welcome Lorenzo Torrent to Physics Stack Exchange. Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you asking about a bound state such as a $^4He^+$ ion? A specific distance is mentioned in the title but not referenced in the question.